# Adding additional run arguments to docker container in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins Pipeline I declare an agent like:

```
agent{dockerfile true}
```

My Dockerfile is in the root of the source repository and I dont want to change that.

Now my question is: How can I provide additional Arguments when Jenkins is running the Container? I have to mount the Docker Socket (for running docker commands in my Pipeline) like:

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than expected, just had to add:

```
agent{dockerfile {args '-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'}}
```

Dont need to change the Destination of the Directory. I think Documentation is here not really clear.